# How to powershell to give warning or error when using an undefined variable?

Tags: powershell

In a powershell script, if I try to use an undefined variable, it continues on its way, not indicating by any warning or error that I did so.

For example, the following script

```
echo "a"
echo $nonexistant_variable
echo "c"
```

gives the output

```
a
c
```

Is there any way to get powerShell to let me know that the variable I'm trying to use is undefined?

Comment: [`Set-StrictMode`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849692.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could consider using the strict mode:

```
Set-strictmode -version latest
```

This will give you warning and errors if you do common mistakes (such as using an undeclared variable etc).

You could also use PSDebug -Strict

```
Set-PSDebug -Strict
```

Comment: Accordings to docs:
`Unlike the Set-PSDebug cmdlet, Set-StrictMode affects only the current scope and its child scopes. Therefore, you can use it in a script or function without affecting the global scope.`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Set-PSDebug`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849697.aspx)'s `-Strict` switch:

> -Strict
>
> Specifies that the interpreter should throw an exception if a variable
>   is referenced before a value is assigned to the variable

```
#I belong in your PowerShell (ISE)-profile
Set-PSDebug -Strict
```

Comment: Technically speaking this is the exact answer, though I still prefer strict mode as you get some more good stuff on top of unassigned variables: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/12/03/enforce-better-script-practices-by-using-set-strictmode/.

Answer (score 1):

While PowerShell does have [`Set-PSDebug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug?view=powershell-7.3) and [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-7.3), fundamentally it is a bad language and is not parsing scripts properly before executing them. It will gladly ignore code that is invalid that it has not run. **There is no way to validate Powershell code without executing it**.

```
Set-PSDebug -strict
Set-StrictMode -version latest
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

if($false)
{
  Write-Output $fnord #undeclared variable
}

#powershell should halt because of an error and not get here.
write-output "this language is clownshoes"
```

yields

```
this language is clownshoes
```

Contrast this to *parse* errors, which behave reasonably:

```
Set-PSDebug -strict
Set-StrictMode -version latest
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

if($false)
{
  () #parseerror
}

#powershell should halt because of an error and not get here.
write-output "this text will not show"
```

yields

```
At line:9 char:4
+   () #parseerror
+    ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
```

So, in short, while you can have powershell error out *when* it attempts to read from an undeclared variable, **there is no way to have powershell properly check your script for undeclared variables at parse-time**.

Comment: By your logic virtually every interpreted language is a "bad language".

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride - Yes.